# rails error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a migration file

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit=>25
      t.string "last_name",  :limit=>25
      t.string "email",     :default=>"" :null=>false
      t.string "password", :limit=> 40
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def down
    deop_table :users
  end
end
```

after making change when I tried to migrate it usin command rake db:migrate I got the error.
please help

Comment: make sure your settings in `config/database.yml` are right

Comment: @user3652573 post your error log